# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'matches' of undefined at AppComponent_Template

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I get this error when i run npm prerender

"prerender": "ng run universalTest:prerender --routesFile routes.txt"

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'matches' of undefined   
    at AppComponent_Template (main.js:1:3578009)   
    at executeTemplate (main.js:1:1184365)  
    at refreshView (main.js:1:1180793)  
    at refreshComponent (main.js:1:1197151)  
    at refreshChildComponents (main.js:1:1183043)  
    at refreshView (main.js:1:1183085)   
    at renderComponentOrTemplate (main.js:1:1184013)   
    at tickRootContext (main.js:1:1198860)  
    at detectChangesInRootView (main.js:1:1199254)   
    at RootViewRef.detectChanges (dist\un√ Prerendering routes to browser complete.
```

Comment: Could you share a bit more about your code? I would have the impression (as mentioned by @Randy) that this is not related to prepender, but something in the code itself.

Comment: sure should i share project.json file?

Comment: If you have a github repo of the project that would be optimal. As an initial test, you could do a global search in your code for the word "matches" and see where it is being used.

Comment: i did that, but other then main.js that gets compiled there is no where matches

Comment: I found these two links that might help. Is there a translation library that you are using in your code?
[https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit/issues/311](https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit/issues/311)
[https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/angular/universal/1216/531618000](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/angular/universal/1216/531618000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you are trying to use "matches" method on something that is undefined.

Comment: Sorry but i am not using matches anywhere, it just comes up on my main.js generated file